# How can I group table by highest record

Tags: sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have sql results:

```
+----------+-----+--------+
|rewardID  |count|playerID|
+----------+-----+--------+
|BurgerKing|5    |1       |
+----------+-----+--------+
|BurgerKing|4    |2       |
+----------+-----+--------+
|KFC       |1    |1       |
+----------+-----+--------+
|KFC       |5    |2       |
+----------+-----+--------+
```

how can i make it to be like

```
+----------+-----+--------+
|rewardID  |count|playerID|
+----------+-----+--------+
|BurgerKing|5    |1       |
+----------+-----+--------+
|KFC       |5    |2       |
+----------+-----+--------+
```

I mean select player who get most reward for each reward row

Answer (score 0):

Try the below

```
select Y.rewardId,Y.count,[playerId] from YourTable Y
join (select [rewardId],MAX([count]) as [count] from YourTable group by [rewardId]) as Y1
on Y.rewardId=Y1.rewardId and Y.[count]=Y1.[count]
```

Tried with the following table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[yourtable]( [rewardid] [nvarchar](50) NULL, [count] [int] NULL, [playerid] [int] NULL )
INSERT INTO [dbo].[yourtable] ([rewardid] ,[count] ,[playerid])
VALUES ('Burger King', 5,1), ('Burger King', 4,2), ('KFC',1,1), ('KFC',6,2) GO
```

And it gave me result

```
rewardid    count   playerid
Burger King  5      1
KFC          6      2
```

Comment: it seems cool . thanks but any way better?

Comment: This doesn't work. Try running the query against `insert into reward values ('BurgerKing', 5, 1), ('BurgerKing', 4, 2), ('KFC', 5, 1), ('KFC', 6, 2)`.

Comment: yeah i found it. doesnt work ! sorry

Comment: Are you sure? I just tried and it is giving me proper result.

Comment: Try it with the dataset I gave. The query is just accidentally working with the OP's dataset because both groups happen to have 5 as the winner. If you make 5 the winner for one and the loser for the other, the loser 5 will still show up.

Comment: Try with KFC,5,1 and KFC,6,2. Not KFC,1,1 and KFC,6,2. :-)

Comment: @Willie Wheele I have updated the answer. I hope it will work for all scenario.

Answer (score 0):

```
select yourtable.rewardid,yourtable.count,yourtable.playerid  from yourtable left join (select distinct rewardid, max(count) OVER (PARTITION BY rewardid)  as maxcount from yourtable) source 
on source.rewardid=yourtable.rewardid and source.maxcount=yourtable.count where source.maxcount is not null
```

This answer is assuming that we want records for each reward id

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.rewardId,t.count,playerId from tableName as t    
join 
(select rewardId,MAX([count]) as cnt 
 from tableName
 group by rewardId
) as t1
on t.rewardId=t1.rewardId and t.count=t1.cnt
```